# WordPress.com VIP theme activation issue - vip-init.php is not found

Tags: wordpress, virtualbox, vagrant-provision

I am setting up my first VIP theme on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS computer by following instructions at:

https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/vip/dev-environment/ and
http://docs.chassis.io/en/latest/quickstart/#prerequisites

At this point I have:

- Virtual Box 5.1 installed
- Vagrant 1:1.9.4 installed

Before writing the steps in detail here is my current folder structure

```
/var/www/html
          |-> thevp (Chassis installation)
              |-> wp
                 |-> wp-content/themes/vip/plugins
                        |         |           |-> vip-init.php
                        |         |-> vp-theme (custom theme)
                        |-> mu-plugins

Vagrant URL: vagrant.local
Admin URL: vagrant.local/wp/wp-admin
```

After installing above two I installed Chassis inside `/var/www/html/thevp` folder. This installed a folder called `wp`, which I believe the default WordPress installation. So now I have `/var/www/html/thevp/wp` (plus other folders and files).
**The wp-content folder sits inside "wp" folder**.

Next I installed **VIP Plugins and Helpers** from svn co https://vip-svn.wordpress.com/plugins/ wp-content/themes/vip/plugins inside `/var/www/html/thevp/wp/wp-content/themes/vip/plugins`.

Then I installed VIP mu-Plugins inside `/var/www/html/thevp/wp/wp-content/mu-plugins`

And finally, I cloned my VIP theme from Github inside `/var/www/html/thevp/wp/wp-content/themes/vp-theme`

After all installations and cloning I ran $vagrant up from within `/var/www/html/thevp/`, which provisioned my Chassis Box and presented with the URL http://vagrant.local/.

The above URL runs fine and opens default site with TwentySeventeen theme.
Under Admin > Themes I can see my own theme vp-theme present along with other default themes WordPress has installed.

But whenever I am trying to Activate this theme I am getting this error message:

> **Warning:
> require_once(/vagrant/content/themes/vip/plugins/vip-init.php): failed
> to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /vagrant/wp/wp-content/themes/vip/yrc-wordpress-theme/functions.php on
> line 9**
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> '/vagrant/content/themes/vip/plugins/vip-init.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
> /vagrant/wp/wp-content/themes/vip/yrc-wordpress-theme/functions.php on
> line 9

Assuming that `/var/www/htm/thevp` is not being recognized as the correct path becausd wp-content folder actually resides under `/var/www/html/thevp/wp` and this should be root, I destroyed running instance of VirtualBox and ran `$ vagrant up` again but this time from inside `/var/www/html/thevp/wp`.

But I still get the same error. How can I resolve this problem?

### Update

I checked my theme's functions.php for the following line

```
require_once WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/vip/plugins/vip-init.php';
```

which is there, but I have a feeling that `WP_CONTENT_DIR` is probably outputting wrong path for some reason as the error message says

```
require_once(/vagrant/content/themes/vip/plugins/vip-init.php)...
```

I can't find any folder `/vagrant/content`.

Comment: Are you manually adding this line? `require_once(/vagrant/content/themes/vip/plugins/vip-init.php)`? Because you should use either built in WordPress or php functions for that, like `get_stylesheet_uri ` or similar...

Comment: no. It is already there. I have been provided with this theme which I have to work on. My objective is to to set this up in my local environment first.

Answer (score 0):

After long research and googling I finally got this to work.

The main reason for the error to come up was the content folder defined in `config.yaml file`.

When Chassis installs, it creates a file called `config.yaml` in its root. This is the default settings in the file under **"path"** section.

```
# Base directory for reference. Relative to the Chassis directory.
base: .

# Where WordPress lives. Relative to the base directory.
wp: wp

# Content directory. Relative to the base directory.
content: content
```

First thing I did was changed `content: content` to `content: wp/wp-content`. Thing to notice here is Chassis creates the default WordPress installation under "wp" not under "Wordpress".

Second thing I needed to change was from `multisite: No` to `multisite: Yes` in the same file.

However, while booting Virtual machine I encountered the following error:

> It appears your machine doesn't support NFS, or there is not an
>   adapter to enable NFS on this machine for Vagrant

That got fixed by installing NFS Common and NFS Kernel Server

```
$ sudo apt-get install nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
```

I encountered another error during VitualBox booting with vagrant. It asked me for my `sudo` password. But after supplying it the execution failed and I received the following message on console:

> The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
>   Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
>
> mount -o 'vers=3,udp' 33.33.33.1:'/home/subrata/' /var/www
>
> Stdout from the command: Stderr from the command: stdin: is not a tty
>   mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not
>   supported

To fix that I had to add the following lines in `/etc/sudoers` file.

```
vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL  
Defaults:vagrant !requiretty
```

Finally I am all set! `$vagrant up` has successfully booted my VM.

http://vagrant.local runs fine as well as now I am able to activate my own VIP theme for the first time :)